# Apollo Client refetch() is not updating cache when the response from server is empty list

Tags: caching, react-apollo, apollo-client, apollo-cache-inmemory

I am using `refetch()` whenever the variables of the useQuery changes in order to filter the list. Every time a variable prop is changed it fetches the results according to the filters, when the results from the server are empty list [], the refetch() method returns the cached results and not the empty list [].

```
const { loading, error, data, fetchMore, refetch } = useQuery(Users, {
    variables: {
      userNumber: userNum,
    },
  });

useEffect(() => {
    if (userNum){
      refetch();
    } 
    }, [userNum]);
```

So it fetches the updated result every time userNum prop changes with the list of users that have this userNum however, if the list of users returned from the server is empty (as no user have this number), I can see the previous cached results instead of an empty list.

I have tried

```
fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network', 
nextFetchPolicy: 'cache-first',
```

and still get the cached results instead of the empty list.

I have also tried the merge() in typePolicies and it worked! However when I apply the relayStylePagination it fetches again the cached results and not the empty list.

```
uri: 'http://localhost:5000/graphql',
cache: new InMemoryCache({
  typePolicies: {
    Query: {
      fields: {
        devices: relayStylePagination(),
        merge(existing = {}, incoming) {
          return { ...existing, ...incoming };
        },
      },
    },
  },
}),
});
```

I have also tried with keyfields and again is working the cached are updated when the server is returning empty list, however the relay pagination is not working. The only way to have the relay pagination work is to place it only like this:

```
fields: {
          devices: relayStylePagination(),
        },
```

`
My query is like this:

```
 $after: ID
 $userNum: Int
 $dpiGt: String
 $dpiLt: String
) {
 users(
   after: $after
   userNumber: $userNum
   first: 30
   filter: { dpiGt: $dpiGt, dpiLt: $dpiLt }
 ) {
   edges {
     cursor
     node {
       id
       name
       userNumber
     }
   }
   pageInfo {
     endCursor
     hasNextPage
   }
 }
}
```

System details:

```
OS: macOS 10.15.4
Binaries:
Node: 12.16.1 - ~/n/bin/node
Yarn: 1.21.1 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
npm: 6.13.4 - ~/n/bin/npm
Browsers:
Chrome: 86.0.4240.80
Firefox: 81.0.1
Safari: 13.1
npmPackages:
@apollo/client: ^3.2.3 => 3.2.5
```

Comment: Have you resolved that?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this will fix your issue but it's worth a try.

After investigating and reading the Apollo documentation, under the [refetch section](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/v2/data/queries/#inspecting-loading-states), I found this description which might be useful to your use case.

> Luckily, the useQuery hook's result object provides fine-grained information about the status of the query via the networkStatus property. To take advantage of this information, we need to set the notifyOnNetworkStatusChange option to true so our query component re-renders while a refetch is in flight:

```js
import { useQuery, NetworkStatus } from '@apollo/client';

...

const { loading, error, data, fetchMore, refetch, networkStatus } = useQuery(Users, { 
    variables: {
      userNumber: userNum,
    },
     notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true, 
  });
  

 if (networkStatus === NetworkStatus.refetch) return <div>Refetching!</div>; 
 
 ...
```